# Trouble with DPTR and DB

Tags: assembly, byte, c-preprocessor, 8051

I'm programming a SciLabs C8051F330 micro controller and daughter card in assembler. I'm struggling with the following code:

```
MOV         DPTR,#200H  ;
CLR         A
MOVC        A,@A+DPTR
MOV         P1,A

ORG         200H
DB          03H
```

According to my debugger the value of A is 03H and the DPTR is 200H, but when I MOV A into P1 the end result is 43H instead of 03H.

Thank you,
Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your all memory up to 200H was not filled then try to minimize it and make it 150H or if possible than make it 100H. And try it again.